# Load html content in UIWebView - iOS

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am loading html content in UIWebview (iPhone6) and the content has actionable buttons. Upon pressing one of the buttons a pop up shows up in the middle of the content (content is approximately 6-7 pages long). As a result, user is unable to see the popup as she is on the first screen. Earlier, I thought it was content's issue, but on android, the pop up comes on the middle of the first page.

```
-(void) loadScorm {

NSString *scormUrl = self.content.media.scormUrl;
scormUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"https:" , scormUrl];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:scormUrl];
NSString *body;
body = //constructed body

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL: url];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
self.webView.frame = self.webViewContainer.frame;
}
```

I also read that javascript for UIWebView is enabled by default. What am I missing? Any pointers would be appreciated.

PS: Can't share the screenshot as the content is classified.

Answer (score 0):

How you create your UIWebView via Code or IBOutlet.

If you are created your webView via IBOutlet then you have to check some webView property in Storyboard like

Then your webView will take Events.

[image: Your property is like this i guess]

[image: Check Events,Links, Addresses,Phone Numbers]

And if you are created your UIWebView via code then write this code

```
[your_webView_Object setDataDetectorTypes: UIDataDetectorTypeAll];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  [webview loadHTMLString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div id ='foo' align='justify' style='font-size:22px; font-family:helvetica; color:#ffffff';>%@<div>",[jsonObject objectForKey:@"msg"]] baseURL:nil];
```

**Hope you will find useful**

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this was an issue from the side of content creator. The person didn't include the support of Safari and Chrome on iOS platform and hence, these issues.